# Send automatic chat message once post is created. Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

When a user creates a post with information such as title, location, description, etc., I want to automatically create a chat with the admin account (unique Firebase UID). I want the first message of that chat to be the information from the post listed above. I have managed to save the  chat with the information, but there is no way for me to retrieve it. Each user posting will be displayed in the users home view as a UITableView with each cell leading to a separate chat with the admin. I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ibjects/simple-text-chat-app-using-firebase-in-swift-5-b9fa91730b6c).

```
    class FinalVC: UIViewController {

   func addPost(value: String, imagesData: [Data]) {
       guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
       let userPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
       let ref = userPostRef.childByAutoId()
  
       let values = ["value": valueFinal, "findersFee": findersFee, "itemTitle": titleOfItem, "itemDescription": descriptionField, "confirmed": isConfirmed, "location": location, "bePresent": shouldBePresent, "verification": "test", "category": categoryTitle, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970] as [String : Any]
 
        
      let users = [self.currentUser.uid, self.user2UID]

      let data = values
                
    let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats")
    db.addDocument(data: data) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Unable to create chat! \(error)")
                        return
                    } else {
                //      self.loadChat()
                    }
                }
    
       ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
                                      if let err = err {
                                          print("Failed to save post to DB", err)
                                          return
                                      }
                                      
                                      print("Successfully saved post to DB")
                           //           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                          
                                  }
   }

class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController, InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate, MessagesDataSource, MessagesLayoutDelegate, MessagesDisplayDelegate {


var currentUser: User = Auth.auth().currentUser!

var user2Name: String?
var user2ImgUrl: String?
var user2UID = "CVKuU1WWo2ScavfrjH4h3HWDSCv1"


   func createNewChat() {
    let users = [self.currentUser.uid, self.user2UID]
     let data: [String: Any] = [
         "users":users
     ]
     
     let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats")
     db.addDocument(data: data) { (error) in
         if let error = error {
             print("Unable to create chat! \(error)")
             return
         } else {
             self.loadChat()
         }
     }
}

func loadChat() {
    
    //Fetch all the chats which has current user in it
    let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats")
            .whereField("users", arrayContains: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found User 1")
    
    
    db.getDocuments { (chatQuerySnap, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        } else {
            
            //Count the no. of documents returned
            guard let queryCount = chatQuerySnap?.documents.count else {
                return
            }
            
            if queryCount == 0 {
                //If documents count is zero that means there is no chat available and we need to create a new instance
                self.createNewChat()
            }
            else if queryCount >= 1 {
                //Chat(s) found for currentUser
                for doc in chatQuerySnap!.documents {
                    
                    let chat = Chat(dictionary: doc.data())
                    //Get the chat which has user2 id
                    if (chat?.users.contains(self.user2UID))! {
                        
                        self.docReference = doc.reference
                        //fetch it's thread collection
                         doc.reference.collection("thread")
                            .order(by: "created", descending: false)
                            .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true, listener: { (threadQuery, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                            return
                        } else {
                            self.messages.removeAll()
                                for message in threadQuery!.documents {

                                    let msg = Message(dictionary: message.data())
                                    self.messages.append(msg!)
                                    print("Data: \(msg?.content ?? "No message found")")
                                }
                            self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                            self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
                        }
                        })
                        return
                    } //end of if
                } //end of for
                self.createNewChat()
            } else {
                print("Let's hope this error never prints!")
            }
        }
    }
}

private func insertNewMessage(_ message: Message) {
    
    messages.append(message)
    messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    }
}
private func save(_ message: Message) {
    
    let data: [String: Any] = [
        "content": message.content,
        "created": message.created,
        "id": message.id,
        "senderID": message.senderID,
        "senderName": message.senderName
    ]
    
    docReference?.collection("thread").addDocument(data: data, completion: { (error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error Sending message: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom()
        
    })
}

// MARK: - InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate

        func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {

            let message = Message(id: UUID().uuidString, content: text, created: Timestamp(), senderID: currentUser.uid, senderName: currentUser.uid)
            
              //messages.append(message)
              insertNewMessage(message)
              save(message)

              inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
              messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
              messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }


// MARK: - MessagesDataSource
func currentSender() -> SenderType {
    
    return Sender(id: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, displayName: Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "Name not found")
    
}
```

Comment: You tagged with `google-cloud-firestore`, but are using the Firebase Realtime Database API in your code. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate and the API for one does not apply to the other. Please make sure the tags reflect the actual technologies you're asking about.

Comment: ^^ Agreed. I would recommend switching your database from "Realtime" to "Cloud Firestore". Cloud Firestore is much easier to work with and scale.

Comment: I am using both Firebase realtime database and Firestore, the chats are being saved to Firestore. That is why I tagged google-cloud-firestore

Comment: That makes the problem quite complex. Is there a way to reproduce the problem by using only one database or the other, isntead of both? Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The question is also a bit unclear. If your 'Admin user' has an observer on a node, say it's called *new_post_notifications* whenever a user creates a post in the posts node, also write the created postId to the *new_post_notifications* node and the admin will receive a notification to which they can retrieve whatever data they need. In Firebase, there are no 'chats' so you can't 'create a chat' - that only exists within the confines of your code. Please clarify what you're asking and reduce your code to a minimal example.